# How can I view my Hard drive's content with a different user other than root. I keep getting permission denied

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I can view the content of my hard drive mounted onto virtual box where i'm running oracle Linux using the root user, but i can't view it with other users. It appears the other users I'm using belong to another "group". The thing is, I want to install a bunch of softwares using another user other than root. the root user belong to a group call wheel. Can any one suggest a way I can view my files with a different user without getting " permission denied "

```
ls -ld sf_G_DRIVE/
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 23 Oct 30 14:30 /media
```

I'm running Oracle Linux on virtual box

Comment: `ls -ld /path/name` where `/path/name` is the place in the filesystem where your hard drive is mounted, please. If that means nothing, please start with an [edit] to question that includes the output of `mount`.

Comment: out put of ls -ld sf_G_DRIVE/ : drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 23 Oct 30 14:30 /media

Comment: That `ls -ld sf_G_DRIVE` won't give the result you've shown. Please re-read what I've asked.